# can we use a single thread by creating and deleting it and again using it?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter and python and using speech recong and talkback for that. The problem is I have to create a lot of threads every time I want the function of talkback to call.is there any way to create a single thread and delete it after using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: @StefanCrain i am lookin for just a function like th.delete() or any thing th.remove whatever....like th,start to start the thread

Comment: The thread automatically dies after the task finishes.